# Not able to use path as string

Tags: linux, unix

I want to use string as a path but its giving an error:
No file or directory.

```
$ path="/home/test"    # Line 1
$ cd $path             # Line 2
```

`cd` command is giving error. How to use this without changing Line 1.
Don't want to use `path=/home/test`.

Comment: your   code works  fine in bash on my desktop.

Comment: what is the error msg ? It works on one of my servers fine

Comment: Perhaps you need to `mkdir $path` before you `cd $path`...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the  EXACT message is 'No such file or directory'  that means /home/test does not  exist